# chrome and firefox JSON.stringify(obj) produces illegal string literals

Tags: javascript, json, string, syntax-error

Using "JSON.stringify" appears to produce illegal strings in both firefox and chrome latest.  Here's my test, all in the console.

First: create an object:

```
x={red:[255,0,0],green:[0,255,0],blue:[0,0,255]}
Object {red: Array[3], green: Array[3], blue: Array[3]}
```

.. but when I use JSON.stringify on x I get an illegal string literal which should have outermost single quotes.

```
xj=JSON.stringify(x)
"{"red":[255,0,0],"green":[0,255,0],"blue":[0,0,255]}"
```

.. but JavaScript thinks it's a string:

```
typeof xj
"string"
```

.. and it works fine with JSON.parse:

```
xjo=JSON.parse(xj)
Object {red: Array[3], green: Array[3], blue: Array[3]}
```

.. on the other hand, entering the stringified string literal directly in the console raises an error:

```
"{"red":[255,0,0],"green":[0,255,0],"blue":[0,0,255]}"
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

.. which does not happen if the two outermost quotes are changed to single quotes.

So is there some sort of magic going on here?  Double quotes are nest-able in JSON?  The MDN JSON page shows outermost single quotes.

What is going on!  Why is JSON allowing illegal strings?

Comment: the surrounding quotes around the string are just there to hint you that you received a string. If you want to use that string with JSON.parse, replace the outer double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: They aren't illegal, it just looks that way from the console, because it's throwing quotes around the value when it's printed.  If you alert(xj) it is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/3nzrd6ow/

Comment: Bergi: could you give a link to the dup?  Thanks.

Comment: Found it in the top comment.  Sorry!

Comment: It's an artifact of the console. Here's another example: `var x = "x\"y"` if you type `x` in the console it will show `"x"y"`. It omits backslashes, making the string non-copy-pasteable.

Comment: Ah..hadn't thought about that: console !== page.  I've found other console issues.  "let" works now in Chrome w/ JS experimental flag, but not in console. Maybe we need a Console Fails list.  :)